# Creating a new column with value dependent on on other columns values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Assuming I have a dataframe looking like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'Column 1': [10, 12,13,43,np.nan], 
    'Column2':[np.nan,7,np.nan,49,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

[image]

I would like to create a third column with a condition to take values from Column 2 unless they are NaNs. So looking like below:

[image]

I have found multiple topics/solutions where the condition was dependent on values in one column but could not find one where it had to provide data from more than one column.

Comment: Not sure what the "multiple topics/solutions" you found but this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column.

Comment: `df['col3'] = df['col2'].fillna(df['col1'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `mask`:

```
df['Column3'] = df['Column2'].mask(df['Column2'].isna(), df['Column 1'])
```

A more generic version (uses any number of columns) would be to take the last valid value per row:

```
df['Column3'] = df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
```

output:

```
   Column 1  Column2  Column3
0      10.0      NaN     10.0
1      12.0      7.0      7.0
2      13.0      NaN     13.0
3      43.0     49.0     49.0
4       NaN      8.0      8.0
```

Comment: I think check NaN is not neccesary

Comment: @ansev there are many ways, I mostly provided an answer for the second option that I found more interesting (but which unfortunately did not seem to be used)

Answer (score 0):

You only need:

```
df['Column3'] = df['Column2'].fillna(df['Column1'])
```

Or:

```
df['Column3'] = df['Column2'].combine_first(df['Column1'])
```